# Install Empire Earth on Ubuntu 18.04 and fix mouse lags

Tags: 18.04, wine, games

So I tried to install the game with wine, configured wine and install few dll components using winetricks, then when starting the game it says, `runtime error due to microsoft C++ library`. Below are the wine logs for it.

```
00b6:fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000006 not handled
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f244,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32edf4,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32edf4,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
00b6:fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000006 not handled
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f244,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32edf4,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32edf4,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
00b6:fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000006 not handled
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f184,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ed34,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ed34,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
00b6:fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000006 not handled
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f184,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ed34,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ed34,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
00b6:fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000006 not handled
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f254,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ee04,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ee04,0x00000000), stub!
00b6:fixme:ddraw:ddraw7_Initialize Ignoring guid {aeb2cdd4-6e41-43ea-941c-8361cc760781}.
00b6:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x150050, 0x1777b0): stub
00b6:err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\dmloader.dll"
00b6:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {d2ac2892-b39b-11d1-8704-00600893b1bd} could be created for context 0x3
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread b6 at address 0x7bc819c4 (thread 00b6), starting debugger...
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
00d1:err:dbghelp_msc:codeview_process_info Unknown CODEVIEW signature 1075000f in module L"empire earth"
0x7bc819c4 DbgBreakPoint in ntdll: int  $3
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (174 modules)
PE    350000-  381000   Deferred        language
PE    3a0000-  3b8000   Deferred        dx7hrdisplay
PE    3d0000-  3ea000   Deferred        dx7hrtnldisplay
PE    400000-  a82000   Export          empire earth
PE    a90000-  bc0000   Export          low-level engine
PE   b2f0000- b2f7000   Deferred        miles sound system mixer
PE  10000000-100e4000   Deferred        sxlrt233
PE  21100000-2115d000   Deferred        mss32
PE  22100000-22114000   Deferred        mssa3d.m3d
PE  22200000-22215000   Deferred        mssa3d2.m3d
PE  22300000-22311000   Deferred        mssds3ds.m3d
PE  22400000-22414000   Deferred        mssds3dh.m3d
PE  22500000-22514000   Deferred        msseax.m3d
PE  22600000-22616000   Deferred        mssfast.m3d
PE  22700000-22716000   Deferred        mssdolby.m3d
PE  22900000-22912000   Deferred        mssdx7sl.m3d
PE  22a00000-22a12000   Deferred        mssdx7sh.m3d
PE  22b00000-22b13000   Deferred        mssdx7sn.m3d
PE  22c00000-22c18000   Deferred        msseax2.m3d
PE  22d00000-22d62000   Deferred        mssrsx.m3d
PE  24100000-2410d000   Deferred        lowpass.flt
PE  24200000-2420d000   Deferred        highpass.flt
PE  24300000-2430d000   Deferred        bandpass.flt
PE  24400000-2440d000   Deferred        reverb1.flt
PE  24500000-24510000   Deferred        reverb2.flt
PE  24600000-24611000   Deferred        reverb3.flt
PE  24700000-2470d000   Deferred        reson.flt
PE  24800000-24810000   Deferred        phaser.flt
PE  24900000-2490d000   Deferred        parmeq.flt
PE  24a00000-24a0d000   Deferred        mdelay.flt
PE  24b00000-24b0d000   Deferred        sdelay.flt
PE  24c00000-24c0d000   Deferred        ringmod.flt
PE  24d00000-24d0d000   Deferred        flange.flt
PE  24e00000-24e0d000   Deferred        chorus.flt
PE  24f00000-24f10000   Deferred        shelfeq.flt
PE  25100000-2510d000   Deferred        compress.flt
PE  25200000-2520d000   Deferred        autopan.flt
PE  25300000-2530e000   Deferred        laginter.flt
PE  25400000-2540b000   Deferred        capture.flt
PE  26400000-2642c000   Deferred        mssv29.asi
PE  26500000-26525000   Deferred        mssv24.asi
PE  26600000-26627000   Deferred        mssv12.asi
PE  26f00000-26f2a000   Deferred        mp3dec.asi
PE  30000000-30059000   Deferred        binkw32
PE  780c0000-78121000   Deferred        msvcp60
ELF 7829c000-78328000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 79d01000-7a800000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7a800000-7a93e000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a93e000   \               opengl32
ELF 7a9a1000-7aa00000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7ab1e000-7abff000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7b400000-7b7f9000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7f9000   \               kernel32
ELF 7b848000-7b8d7000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7b8d7000-7ba00000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7b8f0000-7ba00000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7bb15000-7bba5000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7bba5000-7bc00000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7bc00000-7bd00000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bd00000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c019000-7c0a6000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-11.1.so
ELF 7c0a6000-7c100000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c40b000-7c423000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c423000-7c44e000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7c647000-7c65f000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cb33000-7cb3f000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7cb3f000-7cb5d000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7cce3000-7ccf1000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7ccf1000-7cd18000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7cd18000-7cd2c000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7cd2c000-7cd49000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7cd49000-7cd67000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7cd67000-7cddd000   Deferred        libglx_mesa.so.0
ELF 7ce1d000-7ce7c000   Deferred        libgldispatch.so.0
ELF 7ce7c000-7ce9f000   Deferred        libglx.so.0
ELF 7ce9f000-7cf00000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7cf22000-7cf38000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF 7cf38000-7cf64000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7cf84000-7d0d5000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7cf90000-7d0d5000   \               wined3d
ELF 7d0d5000-7d14c000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7d0e0000-7d14c000   \               ddraw
ELF 7d14d000-7d156000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7d156000-7d15d000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7d15d000-7d168000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7d168000-7d192000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7d170000-7d192000   \               winepulse
ELF 7d192000-7d1b5000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d1a0000-7d1b5000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7d1b5000-7d200000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7d1c0000-7d200000   \               dsound
ELF 7d307000-7d311000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7d311000-7d317000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d35d000-7d395000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d360000-7d395000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d395000-7d39c000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d39c000-7d3a8000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d3a8000-7d3bb000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d3bb000-7d3bf000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d3bf000-7d3cc000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d3cc000-7d3d8000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d3d8000-7d3df000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d3df000-7d3e3000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d3e3000-7d3ed000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d3ed000-7d408000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7d408000-7d40f000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d40f000-7d413000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d413000-7d43f000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d43f000-7d589000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d589000-7d59e000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d5a1000-7d5a4000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d5a4000-7d5a8000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d5a8000-7d5ab000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d5ab000-7d5b3000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d5b3000-7d5b7000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d5b7000-7d5bc000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d5be000-7d64e000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d5d0000-7d64e000   \               winex11
ELF 7d6ac000-7d6de000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d6de000-7d729000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d729000-7d748000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7d748000-7d782000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7d782000-7d83f000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d83f000-7d862000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7d862000-7d888000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF 7d8a8000-7d8d3000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d8b0000-7d8d3000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7d8d3000-7d90a000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7d8e0000-7d90a000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7d90a000-7d924000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7d910000-7d924000   \               wsock32
ELF 7d924000-7d948000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  7d930000-7d948000   \               shcore
ELF 7d948000-7d9b7000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d950000-7d9b7000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7d9b7000-7e37b000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9d0000-7e37b000   \               shell32
ELF 7e37b000-7e39f000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e380000-7e39f000   \               imm32
ELF 7e39f000-7e3e5000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7e3b0000-7e3e5000   \               usp10
ELF 7e3e5000-7e523000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3f0000-7e523000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e523000-7e571000   Deferred        dinput<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e571000   \               dinput
ELF 7e571000-7e59d000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e580000-7e59d000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e59d000-7e657000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e657000   \               winmm
ELF 7e657000-7e6dc000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e660000-7e6dc000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e6dc000-7e837000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6f0000-7e837000   \               ole32
ELF 7e837000-7e8b0000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e840000-7e8b0000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e8b0000-7e9df000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8c0000-7e9df000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e9df000-7ebe9000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9f0000-7ebe9000   \               user32
ELF 7ebe9000-7eca1000   Dwarf           msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7ec00000-7eca1000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7eea1000-7eeb5000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eeb5000-7eed0000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7eed0000-7eede000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eede000-7efe0000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7b54000-f7b59000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7b59000-f7d35000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7d35000-f7d54000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d56000-f7d60000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7d74000-f7f2b000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7f2d000-f7f55000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000033    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002a    0
    00000025    0
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
0000001b winedevice.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 plugplay.exe
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000023    0
00000028 winedevice.exe
    00000030    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    00000029    0
00000031 winedevice.exe
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000032    0
0000003d mscorsvw.exe
    0000003f    0
    0000003e    0
000000b5 (D) C:\Sierra\Empire Earth\Empire Earth.exe
    000000cf   15
    000000ce   15
    000000c9   15
    000000c8    0
    000000c7    0
    000000c6    0
    000000c5    0
    000000bc    0
    000000b6    0 <==
000000b7 explorer.exe
    000000bb    0
    000000ba    0
    000000b9    0
    000000b8    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.0.1
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 5.1 (0)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-50-generic
```

**EDIT:** Now that got fixed, by installing direct music, although I can't make much out the error messages

[image: image of the mouse lag]

Sometimes that happens with the mouse, at times it's that noticeable, at times mouse is just laggy without no display breaking. Tried configs like,

```
mwo=enabled
mwo=force
windowmanagerdecorated=y
windowmanagermanaged=y
```

And gnome mouse accelaration is set to adaptive

Comment: I still can't make anything out of the error messages but installing directmusic did the trick. It worked.